# How to stream data body after a HTTP request with "Expect: 100-continue" header?

Tags: ios, http, stream, nsurlsession

My application streams data over HTTP. **It works** and I do it like that:

-Initialize and start connection:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration* defaultConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

NSInputStream* inputStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:/*data*/];

NSURL* url = /*init from string*/
NSMutableRequest* request : [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBodyStream = inputStream;
[request addValue:@"no-cache" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cache-Control"];
[request addValue:@"9999999" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];  // Weird isn't it? But this is in server's specs for live streaming.

NSURLSessionUploadTask* uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request];
[uploadTask resume];
```

-Part of the `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` implementation:

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
    needNewBodyStream:(void (^)(NSInputStream * bodyStream))completionHandler
{
    NSInputStream* inputStream = nil;
    NSOutputStream* outputStream = nil;

    // Bind inputStream and outputStream

    self.inputStream = inputStream;
    self.outputStream = outputStream;
    [self.outputStream setDelegate:/*NSStreamDelegate implementation*/];
    [self.outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.outputStream open];

    completionHandler(self.inputStream);
}
```

-Part of the `NSStreamDelegate` implementation:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
{
    switch (eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            // to handle...
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
            // Producer/Consumer's consumer here, and when data is available:
            [self.outputStream write:/*data*/ maxLength:/*data length*/];                
            break;
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            // to handle...
            break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            // to handle...
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

To be precise, there is something I don't show in my code: my connection requires Digest authentication. The URL I used to build my request doesn't contains neither login nor password information. Just after I send the first packet, server send me a 401 so my application performs authentication in `didReceiveChallenge:` method and send request with auth (Digest here) and data body is continuously sent. All works like a charm!

Now, my problem. Newer server version only responds at the end of the entire request. So when I send my request and my data body (continuously sent) server ignore data and at the end, send me a 401: I can't perform Digest auth. My solution is to add the header "Expect: 100-continue"... And it works (partially, keep reading ;) ) the server responds to me :D... But no data body is transmitted and the connection is closed juste after my app send back the request with Digest auth informations. Just imagine that I add `[request addValue:@"100-continue" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Expect"];` in my sample code. There is no call in `needNewBodyStream:`at all.

**Abstract (Wireshark trace):**

With my app:

- Send TCP request headers without auth
- Receive HTTP 401
- Send TCP request headers with Digest auth
- Close connection.

With curl and the same headers:

- Send TCP request headers without auth
- Receive HTTP 401
- Send TCP request headers with Digest auth
- Send data... in continuous until the end...
- Close connection.

**EDIT:**

After my app sends the request with Digest auth, the server doesn't response. I think this is the problem and this is why my connection is closed. But curl sends data anyway and I'd like to do the same. Any idea?

**EDIT2:**

Should I implements my own `NSURLProtocol` and remove the `Expect: 100-continue` header after authentication to make my app able to send data body? Better: is there a way to override the default `NSURLProtocol` HTTP specs instead of rewriting it from scratch?

**WORKAROUND (IMPORTANT):**

I make my app works doing a like hack. First, I send a single HTTP (POST) request with neither data nor credentials to force `didReceiveChallenge:` to be called. In this callback I compute authentication with the `NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession` params to bind this information with the session during all its life cycle. Then I cancel this request and create a new one in charge to stream data (exactly like my sample code a the top of this post): Digest auth is included automatically in the first packet sent.

That's a solution to make it works and help people in this case. But it's not the solution I was looking for, so I let this question unresolved and hope for a solution which use the `Expect: 100-continue` and a single request. Thanks!